# Setting an array value = 0 and missing return statement

Tags: java, arrays, null, return

I have a class BankAccount

```
public class BankAccount {
    private double balance;

    public BankAccount() {
        balance = 0;
    }

    public BankAccount(double initialBalance) {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

I also have a an array of those classes within the class BankAccountGroup

```
public class BankAccountGroup {
    private BankAccount[] bankAccounts;

    public BankAccountGroup(BankAccount[] bankAccounts) {
        this.bankAccounts = bankAccounts;
    }

    public double getBalance(int i) throws NullPointerException {
        return bankAccounts[i].getBalance();
    }

    public double removeAccount(int i) throws NullPointerException {
        if(bankAccounts[i] != null) {
            return bankAccounts[i].getBalance();
            bankAccounts[i] = null;
        }

        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Within the method `public double removeAccount(int i)` I want to return the balance in i-th account if that account is not null and then sets that index to null in the array element at index i to null. If that element was already null, return 0.

I then get the error

```
D:\CS 140>javac assignment03\BankAccountGroup.java
assignment03\BankAccountGroup.java:17: error: unreachable statement
                        bankAccounts[i] = null;
                        ^
assignment03\BankAccountGroup.java:23: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
```

I know that the unreachable statement error is basically pointless code to the compiler, but I can't see why. As for the no return statement, there's clearly return statements in both paths that the method could take. My only thought is that the two lines within the if in removeAccount should be switched, but then I can't set the i-th element to null.

Comment: My guess is that both compiler errors will be resolved when you remove the dead code.

Comment: I would suggest to use a list and not an array of "BankAccount"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put business code after "return" statement, as it would be never reached... when you "return" you "exit" from the method.

Try this:

```
 public double removeAccount(int i) throws NullPointerException {
    if(bankAccounts[i] != null) {
        double result = bankAccounts[i].getBalance();
        bankAccounts[i] = null;
        return result;
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it's possible to use a `finally` to run code after a `return`

Comment: @RC. What ?? why `finally ` came here ?

Comment: @RC; Yes, right. That's another solution. Putting your code in a try/finally block depends on the situation, tho. Here I think it would be awkward.

Comment: `try { return bankAccounts[i].getBalance(); } finally { bankAccounts[i] = null}` should work (I agree it's a hack here)

Answer (score 2):

This code is bogus:

```
    if(bankAccounts[i] != null) {
        return bankAccounts[i].getBalance();
        bankAccounts[i] = null;
    }
```

No statement after return will be executed. Think of a way to preserve the return result, set the pointer to null and then return. You will need a helper variable.

Answer (score 2):

Once you return from the metohd, there is no point of executing next lines of code. That's the reason you are seeing that exception. And it wouldn't make much sense making it null after you return it.

And you can do something like this

```
      if(bankAccounts[i] != null) {
            double balance = bankAccounts[i].getBalance();
            bankAccounts[i] = null;
            return balance;
        }
```

Comment: I took the liberty to change the data type from `long` to `double`, as per the method signature ;)

Comment: @Laf You saved my life ;)